# jQuery date script won't populate field unless it is text input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that populates one of the fields in my form to today's date, however it only works when the input type is set to 'text'. PHP/SQL won't accept this value as the SQL datatype is set to 'date'. If anyone could explain how I might make this script compatible with the date input type I would greatly appreciate it.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="flight_date">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input id="flight_date" type="date" class="form-control" maxlength="10" name="flight_date">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

var today = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

document.getElementById('flight_date').value = today;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/ygL4gjbd/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html `<input type="date" />` supports date only in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd) format. So you can do it like following.

```js
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

var today = year +"-" + month + "-" + day;

document.getElementById('flight_date').value = today;
```

```html
<input id="flight_date" type="date" class="form-control" maxlength="10" name="flight_date">
```

Answer (score 1):

To make `input` accept the date format, you have to insert date string in yyyy-MM-dd format.

so change:

```
var today = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

to:

```
var today = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) does not always expose the property "valueAsDate" in all browsers.

The [valueAsDate.polyfill.js](https://gist.github.com/sylvainpolletvillard/0aa9df9c180cd007e5e1) offers the possibility to extend this property on IE and FF.

The result is:

```js
if(!("valueAsDate" in HTMLInputElement.prototype)){
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "valueAsDate", {
    get: function(){
      var d = this.value.split(/\D/);
      return new Date(d[0], --d[1], d[2]);
    },
    set: function(d){
      var day = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2),
          month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
          datestr = d.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+day;
      this.value = datestr;
    }
  });
}


var date = new Date();
document.getElementById('flight_date').valueAsDate = date;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="flight_date">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input id="flight_date" type="date" class="form-control" maxlength="10" name="flight_date">
    </div>
</div>
```